# Why does my GAIN remain constant after a few cycles?

Tags: matlab, kalman-filters

I am assuming that GAIN is the matrix P?

[From this example:](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18217-learning-the-unscented-kalman-filter/content/ukf.m)

```
function [x,P]=ukf(fstate,x,P,hmeas,z,Q,R)
% UKF   Unscented Kalman Filter for nonlinear dynamic systems
% [x, P] = ukf(f,x,P,h,z,Q,R) returns state estimate, x and state covariance, P 
% for nonlinear dynamic system (for simplicity, noises are assumed as additive):
%           x_k+1 = f(x_k) + w_k
%           z_k   = h(x_k) + v_k
% where w ~ N(0,Q) meaning w is gaussian noise with covariance Q
%       v ~ N(0,R) meaning v is gaussian noise with covariance R
% Inputs:   f: function handle for f(x)
%           x: "a priori" state estimate
%           P: "a priori" estimated state covariance
%           h: fanction handle for h(x)
%           z: current measurement
%           Q: process noise covariance 
%           R: measurement noise covariance
% Output:   x: "a posteriori" state estimate
%           P: "a posteriori" state covariance
```

I plot P[0,0] is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is the state covariance matrix, not the Kalman gain, though the Kalman gain $K$ is usually calculated using it.

It is normal in simple Kalman filters (ones that do not vary with time) for the state covariance matrix to stabilize after a while so that it is constant.

See, for example, [the plots in Figure 3(b) and 3(c) in this PDF](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ian/Teaching/Estimation/LectureNotes2.pdf) which show how both the Kalman gain $K$ and the state covariance $P$ go to a constant value after a relatively short space of time.

Because this happens, the Kalman filter evolution is often ignored in practice and the steady state version is what is implemented.

[image]

Comment: but shouldn't the gain vary in this case - as I am using an unscented kalman filter?

Comment: That depends: do your $f$ and $h$ functions vary with time? Are they nonlinear?

Comment: Ah, glad you asked me that! 

I have 6 states. Each of which is a stock price. I am trying to estimate the first one from the other 5. But there is no reall "law" - they are just correlated. So, currently I am using:

f=@(x)x();  % nonlinear state equations
h=@(x)x();                               % measurement equation

Comment: I really would appreciate your advice on what could be used for f(). I have very little experience of this area, and find the literature confusing.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a completely different question.  If the $f$ and $h$ functions are as you say, then I believe there is no nonlinearity. And they don't change with time.  So I think that means the unscented Kalman filter will just become the standard Kalman filter.  How to really choose them will depend on your application: what are you measuring?  What are you trying to estimate? What are the dynamics of what you're trying to estimate vs what you can measure? Please ask a new question with this information in it.

Comment: OK. I have started a new question